# Android: Check a high score SQL table and add score

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that holds the high scores of a game. I can successfully add a new score and I can show all the scores, but I'd like to add a check so that

1. There are at most 5 rows
2. The rows are always sorted
3. Only add if the new score beats the scores already on the table

Here's my leaderboard.java adding a random score:

```
// Check if high score

// Add to leaderboard
if (Difficulty.equals("Hard")){
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute("add_hminfo", rank, correct, timed);
}
```

Me adding a new row using ASyncTask in backgroundtask.java

```
else if (method.equals("add_hminfo")){
 String rank = params[1];
 String score = params[2];
 String time = params[3];

 SQLiteDatabase db = dbops.getWritableDatabase();
 dbops.addhmLeaderboard(db, rank, score, time);
 return "High Score added";

}
```

And my SQL insertion into the database

```
public void addhmLeaderboard(SQLiteDatabase db,String rank, String score, String time){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(TableInfo.LB_RANK, rank);
    cv.put(TableInfo.LB_SCORE, score);
    cv.put(TableInfo.LB_TIME, time);

    db.insert(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME3, null, cv);
    //Log.d("Database Operations", "One row inserted");
}
```

I currently have rank in my database simply as a placeholder as all "1"s. Ideally this would be my primary key that automatically increments 1-5, but I'm a little confused on that as well.

How can I check to see if a new score is in the top 5 of scores, and then add that new score in the necessary spot?

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to archive, Do you need help to query the results?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your post as a specific question, rather than as a general plea for help? That should make it easier for people to help you out.

Comment: Updated the question. My leaderboard currently displays all scores in no particular order. I would like it to instead display the top 5 scores, in order. To do this, I need to figure out if a new score is in the top 5, and then place it in the correct position. That is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the top 5 scores you can query:

```
db.query(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME3, null, null, null, null, null, TableInfo.LB_SCORE + " DESC, " + TableInfo.LB_TIME + " ASC", "5");
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Do you think I should delete the scores that are not on the top 5 though? 

Also, This sorts by LB_SCORE perfectly. Do you know how if LB_SCORE is equal, to then sort by LB_TIME?

Comment: @Milap check now, and yes, you can delete older values if you want.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfect. How would you suggest to delete rows that are not in that query?

Comment: I would make a list of the top 5 id (assuming that you have an auto numeric primary key) and the I'll call to db.delete where " NOT IN " my list.